# lambda function always return function timeout, even after user callback(null, responce)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

```
const mongo = require('mongoose');
const MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb atles url connection string'
const db = require('./model')

exports.main = (event, context, callback) => {
    mongo.connect(MONGODB_URI,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    mongo.connection.once('open',async ()=>{enter code here
        console.log('SUCCESSFUL DB CONNECTION!!')
        putData();
    }).on('error',(err)=>{
        console.log('ERROR IN DATABASE CONNECTION!!',err)
    })

    const putData = async ()=>{
        const res = await db.create({
                updated_at:new Date(),
                user_id:event.user_id,
                question_id:event.question_id,
            })
            console.log(res)
            callback(null, res)
    }
}
```

everything working perfectly,,  data saved to the database  even the console log before callback giving the output. but callback not working..  callback working when used like this `callback('error')`...

this is the log..

```
2020-03-30T04:48:59.035Z    7e148909-607d-4c71-9c07-3c45827c5b5c    INFO    SUCCESSFUL DB CONNECTION!!
2020-03-30T04:48:59.413Z    7e148909-607d-4c71-9c07-3c45827c5b5c    INFO    {
  updated_at: 2020-03-30T04:48:59.072Z,
  _id: 5e817a3b36599000080f69fb,
  user_id: '2637128638162391923',
  question_id: '123812u31',
  __v: 0
}
END RequestId: 7e148909-607d-4c71-9c07-3c45827c5b5c
REPORT RequestId: 7e248909-607d-4c71-9c07-3c45827c5b5c  Duration: 3003.30 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 94 MB  Init Duration: 516.80 ms    
2020-03-30T04:49:00.979Z 7e248909-607d-4c71-9c07-3c45827c5b5c Task timed out after 3.00 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function execution continues until the event loop is empty or the function times out. So the response will be delayed until all the tasks in the event loop are completed.

You can set [`context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-context.html) to immediately send the response.

More information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-sync).